# JMeter CPU Utilization Report

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can we get CPU Utilization while performing load testing on Jmeter with 1000 users?
Are there any plugins available for CPU Utilization, Memory Calculations in JMeter?

Comment: Alies u have any idea abt the question?

Comment: looking through your questions list I cannot see at least one accepted - I'm not sure I want to have any idea about it.

Answer (score 2):

The perfmon plugin for jmeter is ere: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/PerfMon

Comment: Hi Andrey, Is this plugin is for OS Level or DB Level? Do u have any idea about JMeter plugin which can capture Oracle DB Parameters?

Comment: This can be achieved with EXEC and TAIL metrics in perfmon